# How to execute a Js method from a laravel view?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, adminlte

Does anyone know how I can call js methods from laravel view from other place . I have js methods that I run on views, but I don't want to repeat the same methods over and over for each view. I am using adminlte laravel template. and I need to show different alerts from sweetalert2, depending on the controller's response.

These are the js methods that it executes in each view

```
<script>
@if (session('guardo'))
Swal.fire({
  position: 'center',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Se ha creado correctamente',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
@endif



@if (session('actualizo'))
Swal.fire({
  position: 'center',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Se ha Actualizado correctamente',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
@endif
</script>
```

This is how from the controller I pass the data to view, so that some js method is executed.

```
return redirect()->route('usuario.index')->with('actualizo', 'ok');
```

or also

```
return redirect()->route('usuario.index')->with('guardo', 'ok');
```

Everything works, but I don't want to be putting the same js logic, in each view, I would like to have the logic in one place, and then just call it to run, thanks.

Comment: If you have a base or layout blade file you can move the <script> code there.

Comment: If it's based on layout, but in "adminlte", with adminLte, I can't find a layout: master where I can put this.

code of my blade example:

@extends('adminlte::page')

The 'page' it does not exist as a layout.

Answer (score 0):

the solutio to import principal views

php artisan adminlte:install --type=full --with=main_views